# EF cannot see affected row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mariadb

I have a issue when I try to inserts data to the table. I am using a EF, MariaDB and 'unfortunatelly' trigger. When I try to insert new data, EF throws exception `OptimisticConcurrencyException`.

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoIncrdata BEFORE INSERT ON data
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE new_id integer;
SET new_id = (select max(id_data) + 1 from data);
IF (NEW.id_data < 1) then
    SET NEW.id_data = COALESCE(new_id, 1 );
END IF;
END
```

The exception shows after simple insert:

```
var v = new Data
{
    Id = someObject.Id,
    Location = "text",
    Name = "Data_" + someObject.Id
};
mariaDb.Add(v);
mariaDb.SaveChanges();
```

Exception:

```
InnerException  {"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."}  System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException}
```

SaveChanges() implementations - RepositoryPattern:

```
    public virtual void SaveChanges()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Is there any way how to teach EF the trigger or I should modify the trigger? I need a table with autoincrement primary key and with possibility of inserting pk via EF. If I have a table just with autoincrement on id column so the EF overrides inserted id after `SaveChanges()`.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What happens if you leave out setting the Id property?

Comment: Same problem, EF does not like my trigger.

Comment: Take a look at this. Seems to be same issue. Not sure about the MariaDB part though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820992/error-when-inserting-into-table-having-instead-of-trigger-from-entity-data-frame

Comment: It looks like same problem, but MariaDb does not support INSTEAD OF INSERT.

Comment: For now, I create workaround via `MySqlCommand`. It works but it is a little bit hack in my code because I am using EF everywhere but for this one operation is used completely different technology.