# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected > number of rows (0)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I am working on creating WCF restful Services and when I try adding a record via entity framework into my database I get this exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded.

I have a trigger created at my database which works as:

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_groupLocation_date]
    ON [dbo].[groupLocation]
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NoCount ON
        DECLARE @s int
        DECLARE @g_id int
        DECLARE @lat float
        DECLARE @lon float
        SELECT @s = sender FROM inserted
        SELECT @g_id = g_id FROM inserted
        SELECT @lat = latitude FROM inserted
        SELECT @lon = longitude FROM inserted

        insert into [groupLocation] (sender,g_id,latitude,longitude) values(@s,@g_id,@lat,@lon)
    END
```

One thing to note is that I am able to add records directly into the database. I read some details regarding the exception from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1836173/6181692), and After some research I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6819813/6181692) question at stackoverflow. But while trying the solution I read that DbContext doesn't have a Refresh() method so Instead I tried:

```
var ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
ctx.Refresh();
```

But I still gets the same exception. Then I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20271991/6181692) that only if you are using code first approach then this work around can work, I am using "EF designer from database approach". How can I get access to Refresh method in data first approach?

Comment: for some time you can comment the trigger and then try, what exception are thrown now. because EF may not allow other changes at same time

Comment: If i comment out the trigger then service runs smoothly and there is no exception thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this line of SQL code inside your trigger **AFTER** the insert:

```
select g_id from [groupLocation] where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and g_id = scope_identity();
```

I assume `g_id` is your identity column, if not replace both occurences of `g_id` in the statement above with the identity column.

Also read this SO question - [Error when inserting into table having instead of trigger from entity data framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820992/error-when-inserting-into-table-having-instead-of-trigger-from-entity-data-frame)